# com.mysql.jdbc.Driver not found

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, servlets, connector-j

I am using eclipse for creating servlets. I downloaded the `mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar`
(connector/j) and added the jar file to build path of my project. I can use the classes in 
`mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.jar` (IDE gives me hints and all that stuff and there is no problem using those classes in compile time) . but when i run the servlet i get this error:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

It sounds like suddenly the `com.mysql.jdbc.Driver` class that i've been using can not be found!

When i use the jar file for java SE projects it works perfect but it doesn't work with javaEE.
How can i fix this?

Comment: Not build path, you need to add it as the runtime classpath.

Comment: @evanwong thanks. it worked. i would really appreciate it if you could post this as the answer so other people can use it...

Comment: Cool, put it as the asnwer. : )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The database connector jar should be set as the runtime classpath instead of the build paths since database driver is a runtime dependency.

Answer (score 0):

- Drop the jar into the WEB-INF/lib folder.
- WEB-INF/lib folder is for application specific jars.
- You could also use your servlet container's common/lib folder for
  jars which are common to several web applications.